# ERROR: COPY quote must be a single one-byte character

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

```sql
COPY public.performance (fl_date, mkt_carrier, mkt_carrier_fl_num, origin, origin_city_name, origin_state_abr, dest, dest_city_name, dest_state_abr, dep_delay_new, arr_delay_new, cancelled, cancellation_code, diverted, carrier_delay, weather_delay, nas_delay, security_delay, late_aircraft_delay) 
FROM '/Users/akind/OneDrive/Desktop/SQL/querying-data-postgresql/OntimeCarrier.csv' 
DELIMITER ',' 
CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8' 
QUOTE '\"' 
ESCAPE '''';
```

After running this command, I got the error: `COPY quote must be a single one-byte character`. I have tried checking solutions on the web but none of them suit my needs.

Comment: You don't need to escape the double-quote character. It's just `QUOTE '"'`.

Comment: @AdamKG make it the answer so its quicker to find for others maybe, thanks anyways

Answer (score 3):

```
COPY public.performance (fl_date, mkt_carrier, mkt_carrier_fl_num, origin, origin_city_name, origin_state_abr, dest, dest_city_name, dest_state_abr, dep_delay_new, arr_delay_new, cancelled, cancellation_code, diverted, carrier_delay, weather_delay, nas_delay, security_delay, late_aircraft_delay) 
FROM '/Users/Public/Documents/postgres_coding/code/OntimeCarrier.csv'
DELIMITER ',' 
CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8' 
QUOTE '"' 
ESCAPE '''';
```

Comment: I am getting error - 

```
SQL Error [58P01]: ERROR: could not open file "/Users/prats/Downloads/querying-data-postgresql/OntimeCarrier.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
  Hint: COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
```